# Activity theme not changing

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a `styles.xml` where I have defined styles

```
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Dark styles -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->

<style name = "AppBgDark">
    <item name="android:background">#333333</item>
</style>
<style name = "CardBgDark">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corners_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="event_title_dark">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
<style name="event_date_dark">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
<style name="event_location_dark">
    <item name="android:textColor">#aaa</item>
</style>
<style name="event_calendar_dark">
    <item name="android:textColor">#aaa</item>
</style>
<style name="Actionbar_dark" parent= "Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
     <item name = "android:background">#333333</item>
```

the same way for a light theme as well.
Then i have created a  themes.xml and a attrs.xml to refference these styles.

The problem is when i apply the references from the attrs.xml in the layout i can see no changes happening
For example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardlayout"
        style="?card_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="7dp" >
```

where am I going wrong? Any suggestions? I am really confused!!!

Comment: Perhaps,your parent layout or application replaces theme of your cardlayout.

Comment: @ Yahor10 can you please explain your comment

Comment: If you set in AndroidManifest.xml another theme for application- its replace your cardlayout theme.Check that you use only one style="?card_background" in your layout